# Report rule where `Date Field` is less than `Date Field`?

Tags: reporting

I'm trying to create a report where one date field is compared to another. For example, where Close Date in an Opportunity is Less than Last Modified Date.

How can I do this? I know of being able to use `TODAY` and an actual date, of course, but how do I compare a field to another field in Reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that is possible with standard SalesForce reporting, you could create a formula field checkbox that is true when that condition is met and report on that.

Comment: Well that leads me to the question, how do I create a formula field off of a field that's generated from an audited field? For example, the 'Edit Date' field is one which appears in the Opportunity field auditing reports. I don't see this field within a formula field's 'Insert Field' list.

Comment: Is there a specific field change you are trying to calculate the date from? If you want to know is closedate > closedate last modified date, you could create a date field that gets updated by workflow rule whenever the closedate changes.

Comment: That is indeed what I'm precisely trying to do. I don't understand why I would need to create a new date field that gets updated by a workflow when the 'Edit Date' field has already been created by Salesforce for fields in objects that are being auditing. Is there no way to access that field?

Comment: Opportunity Field History is actually a child object of the opportunity, the only way to do that would be through a trigger using soql, no way to roll it up to the opportunity.